# Custom loss function for U-net in keras using class weights: `class_weight` not supported for 3+ dimensional targets

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

Here's the code I'm working with (pulled from Kaggle mostly):

```
inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
...
outputs = Conv2D(4, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='dice', metrics=[mean_iou])

results = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=8, epochs=30, class_weight=class_weights)
```

I have 4 classes that are very imbalanced. Class A equals 70%, class B = 15%, class C = 10%, and class D = 5%. However, I care most about class D. So I did the following type of calculations: `D_weight = A/D = 70/5 = 14` and so on for the weight for class B and A. (if there are better methods to select these weights, then feel free)

In the last line, I'm trying to properly set class_weights and I'm doing it as so: `class_weights = {0: 1.0, 1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 14}`.

However, when I do this, I get the following error.

> `class_weight` not supported for 3+ dimensional targets.

Is it possible that I add a dense layer after the last layer and just use it as a dummy layer so I can pass the class_weights and then only use the output of the last conv2d layer to do the prediction?

If this is not possible, how would I modify the loss function (I'm aware of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46505819/8100895), however, just passing in the weights in to the loss function won't cut it, because the loss function is called separately for each class) ? Currently, I'm using the following loss function:

```
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

def bce_dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 0.5 * binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)
```

But I don't see any way in which I can input class weights. If someone wants the full working code see this [post](https://www.kaggle.com/mauddib/data-science-bowl-tutorial-using-cnn-tensorflow). But remember to change the final conv2d layer's num classes to 4 instead of 1.

Comment: Your last layer should be a Dense layer with 3 outputs, NOT a Conv layer. Because with current architecture you will end up with a 3D feature map and that's why you get the error.

Comment: So is it better to have another dense player after that Conv layer or should I replace the Conv layer? I'm using that layer to stay true to the original network structure of a U-net.

Comment: Yes, for Unet you will need the 3D feature map, but you will have to find another way to balance your classes. You can do it when you are feeding the data to model.

Comment: You can try out `sample_weights` instead for class imbalance problem

Comment: @Sina can you elaborate on "when feeding data to model?"

Comment: When you call model.fit with X_train, for 3-class problem your X_train should contain equal number of samples from three classes. Let's say the batch size is 6 then X_train should be [C1_sample1,C1_sample2, C2_sample1, C2_sample2, C3_sample1, C3_sample2].

Comment: @Jonathan I have the same problem but my input is one_hot encoded. Will there be an effect also for onehot encoded inputs?

Comment: Yes you can do it with one hot encoded as well. You just need to configure accordingly. This question is quite outdated, there are easier ways to do it with the newer versions of keras @shankarram

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can always apply the weights yourself.

The `originalLossFunc` below you can import from `keras.losses`.
The `weightsList` is your list with the weights ordered by class.

```py
def weightedLoss(originalLossFunc, weightsList):

    def lossFunc(true, pred):

        axis = -1 #if channels last 
        #axis=  1 #if channels first


        #argmax returns the index of the element with the greatest value
        #done in the class axis, it returns the class index    
        classSelectors = K.argmax(true, axis=axis) 
            #if your loss is sparse, use only true as classSelectors

        #considering weights are ordered by class, for each class
        #true(1) if the class index is equal to the weight index   
        classSelectors = [K.equal(i, classSelectors) for i in range(len(weightsList))]

        #casting boolean to float for calculations  
        #each tensor in the list contains 1 where ground true class is equal to its index 
        #if you sum all these, you will get a tensor full of ones. 
        classSelectors = [K.cast(x, K.floatx()) for x in classSelectors]

        #for each of the selections above, multiply their respective weight
        weights = [sel * w for sel,w in zip(classSelectors, weightsList)] 

        #sums all the selections
        #result is a tensor with the respective weight for each element in predictions
        weightMultiplier = weights[0]
        for i in range(1, len(weights)):
            weightMultiplier = weightMultiplier + weights[i]


        #make sure your originalLossFunc only collapses the class axis
        #you need the other axes intact to multiply the weights tensor
        loss = originalLossFunc(true,pred) 
        loss = loss * weightMultiplier

        return loss
    return lossFunc
```

---

For using this in `compile`:

```
model.compile(loss= weightedLoss(keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, weights), 
              optimizer=..., ...)
```

### Changing the class balance directly on the input data

You can change the balance of the input samples too.

For instance, if you have 5 samples from class 1 and 10 samples from class 2, pass the samples for class 5 twice in the input arrays.

.

### Using the `sample_weight` argument.

Instead of working "by class", you can also work "by sample".

Create an array of weights for each sample in your input array: `len(x_train) == len(weights)`

And `fit` passing this array to the `sample_weight` argument.
(If it's `fit_generator`, the generator will have to return the weights along with the train/true pairs: `return/yield inputs, targets, weights`)

Comment: This seems to be compiling, thank you. Can you offer some explanation on the `classSelectors` portion of the code? Also, another thing I added in my code to make yours work as to cast both parameters into `K.equal` as tf.int64 just to be safe. Otherwise, that will also cause an error sometimes.

Comment: Seems to work, thank you! I'll award the bounty in a couple days, just to give others to a chance to answer as well

Comment: Ok, explained :) -- Also added a third option, using the `sample_weight` argument.

Comment: Just to confirm the sample_weight usage, let's say I have only 2 training images, and 2 classes. Then would my sample weights array look something like `weights = [ [0 : 1, 1 : 10] , [0 : 1, 1 : 15] ]`

Comment: One weight for each image: [w1, w2]

Comment: There's a small error in your code. The way I have defined class_weights in my code doesn't work with your code. It takes the index values of the class instead of the actual weight. For the weights to work, it would be `[c1_w, c2_w, c3_w, c4_w]`

Comment: `class_weight` and `sample_weight` work differently. With `sample_weight` it's one single array with the same length as `x_train`. With `class_weight` it's a dictionary with the class number as key and weight as value.

Comment: Here, take a look at this: https://ibb.co/fsg9hz and this: https://ibb.co/e3EC2z . I've added examples of your code's output with both a dict and a list.

Comment: That statement is also wrong. Your code is using class weights, not sample weights, but instead of it needing to be in dictionary format, it's in list format, with the indices of the list representing the classes. I can't pass in `class_weights` into `fit` because of the error message in the OP. I've edited your post.

Comment: Right. Sorry for answering too fast. Indeed, I used a list of class weights instead of a dictionary. (The easiest way I found to code that).

Comment: sadly I get error while I try to compile my model:


....
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype int64: 'Tensor("loss_1/conv2d_transpose_1_loss/ArgMax:0", shape=(?, ?, ?), dtype=int64)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
....

Comment: Well.... take a look at your data types and tensor types in your model. All of them should have the same type.

Comment: I got it working by modifying line:                  classSelectors = [K.equal(i, classSelectors) for i in range(len(weightsList))] 


 Now instead I have two lines as: 

First: one64 = np.ones(1, dtype=np.int64)  

and second:         classSelectors = [K.equal(one64[0]*i, classSelectors) for i in range(len(weightsList))]

Comment: In your first suggestion, the Loss Function, is it normal to true are set to None in trainning?

Comment: @JoãoCastilho, I don't understand your question. Nothing is `None` there.

Comment: @DanielMöller when i'm fitting the model, the variable true of LossFunc is a tensor with shape (None, None, None, None). Is that normal or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: It's normal to get the dimension 0 as `None`. The others depend on whether you defined them as variable or fixed. For images with fixed sizes: `(None, size1, size2, channels)`, for images with variable sizes: `(None, None, None, channels)`. But it's very uncommon to have a `None` in the channels dimension. Is your model just a regular model or you created custom operations?

Comment: @DanielMöller I created a model from functional API - Keras. My pred variable has a shape (None, 335,255,15) but the true variable is set as (None, None, None, None). It should not be equal?

Comment: It should, but maybe it's something related to newer versions.... I don't think it will be a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208071/discussion-between-joao-castilho-and-daniel-moller).

Comment: @DanielMöller Does this loss function also effect if my input is one_hot encoded?

Comment: @shankarram, loss functions don't see "input", only model's "output". The answer is written for one-hot encoded outputs.

Comment: For models operating on 2 classes only, what should be changed? I tried with `weightedLoss(keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, [1.0, 50.0])` but didn't work.